# Can we re-call another Thread Group if the existing thread Group throw error in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Due to the limitation of Test Users Ids, we were only running the test with 3 Test Ids, these Test Ids can have **max 1 session**, if we login manually on another browser or machine it will kill the existing session.

Based on this limitation, I used **Setup Thread Group** to login, **Teardown Thread Group** for Logout and **Thread group** where I searched a few Items. On this Thread Group, I was successfully able to execute 20 users Load test where users were searching items and I was able to achieve the throughput target, even though the users' login session was 3, but problems occurred after 20 min of test when a session of Test user ids expire and Thread Group starting giving error.

My requirement is to run a load test for 1 hr with 20 user load on Thread Group, is it possible to recall setup Thread group so that I can achieve my requirement or if you have any other approach please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically it's possible to use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm) to conditionally call something in another Thread Group, but I don't think setUp Thread Group is a good candidate because it's executed before the main Thread Group.

It worth switching to "normal" Thread Group and the easiest solution would be just letting it run continuously and re-login each 19 minutes so the session would be "refreshed", the delay can be introduced using [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) of [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler.

In the main Thread Group you can either introduce some "Startup delay" in order to let the first Thread Group to login:

[image]

or use the aforementioned [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) if you need to start main threads right after logging in without any extra delay